# SQL Server How to Find the customers who have bought a product from EACH store?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that will list all the customers who have bought an item from EVERY single store in the state of Texas.

So here are 4 tables and their attributes:

```
Customers:
customerID, CustomerName 

Purchases:
CustomerID, ProductID 

StoresInventory:
StoreID, ProductID

StoreLocation:
StoreID, State
```

I can make a query that returns all the stores in Texas, but I'm not sure how to check if a customer has bought products from all of these stores.  Also, I can't use `count` or `aggregation`.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Well, I've tried using a subquery that lists the stores in Texas, however, I can't figure out how to use this subquery exactly to return results only if it matches.  The queries I've written return all customers who bought from at least one store in Texas, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like this:

```
Select c.CustomerId From Customers c
Inner Join Purchases p on C.CustomerId=p.CustomerId
Inner Join StoresInventory s on s.ProductID=p.ProductID
Group By c.CustomerId
Having COUNT(Distinct s.StoreId)=(Select Count(Distinct StoreId) From StoreLocation Where State='Texas')
```

Comment: How would I do this without using count?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the ProductID is unique to a Store; the data you want is not stored in the schema. You know what Customers bought what products and what Stores stock those products but you do not have stored which store a customer bought a product from.

Comment: Yes, assume that the ProductID is unique to a Store.  So you can get the store information through the productID.  Sorry, I was trying to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.customerid
FROM purchases a
JOIN store_inventory b
    ON a.productid=b.productid
GROUP BY  a.customerid
HAVING count(distinct storeid)= 
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM store_location s);
```